# Auto-Encoder の 分類について。どなたか助けてください。

Tags: python, chainer

### 試していること

Chainer で Stacked Auto-Encoder を試してみた ( MNISTデータを利用 )

- ホームページ : http://wazalabo.com/chainer-stacked-auto-encoder.html
- [プログラムソース ( Github )](https://github.com/ISP-Kazuki-Nagasawa/chainer_1.6_sda_mnist_sample)
- 対象ファイル

  - chainer_1.6_sda_mnist_sample-master/libs/stacked_auto_encoder.py
  - chainer_1.6_sda_mnist_sample-master/execute.py
  - chainer_1.6_sda_mnist_sample-master/settings.py

### できていること

上記ホームページのプログラムは、正常に動作したことを確認。

### したいこと

上記、Stacked Auto-Encoder で 学習済み後に、
１つのテストデータ(784次元)を入力し、
最終出力層からのテスト出力結果が、正解/不正解に関係なく、
０〜９までの１０分類の内、何番目に分類されたのかを知りたい。

なお、ホームページ作成者のプログラムは、
最終出力層のニューロン数(ユニット数)は、２つであり、
これは、(x, y) 座標用に、２出力しているようです。

下記、追加修正の仕方はトンチンカンなのでしょうか？
どこをどのように追加変更すれば、分類された確認ができるのでしょうか？

或いは、Keras だったら、こうすればいいよ、というのでもいいので、
教えて頂けたらとても有難いです。

### プログラムを追加した箇所

#### `stacked_auto_encoder.py` ファイル内

```
class StackedAutoEncoderForwardAll( chainer.Chain ) :
    ........
    def __call__( self, x ) :
        ........
        y = self.__getitem__( "l_f{0}".format(self.len_f_layers) )( h )
        print( "y.data_before : ", y.data )    # 追加した行！！！( 確認用 )
        y = F.softmax( y )                     # 追加した行！！！
        print( "y.data_after : ", y.data )     # 追加した行！！！( 確認用 )
        return y
```

#### `settings.py` ファイル内

```
# Layer settings
INPUT_SIZE  = 28 * 28                                      # = 784
OUTPUT_SIZE = 10                                           # 変更した行！！！ .... 2 を 10 に変更した。
LAYER_SIZES = [INPUT_SIZE, 1000, 500, 250, OUTPUT_SIZE]    # NN層 : [ 784, 1000, 500, 250, 10 ]
```

### Softmax関数前後の `y.data` 表示

#### 上記 `print( "y.data_before : ", y.data )` の表示

```
y.data_before :  [[ 0.16361719  0.0925117   0.14825995 -0.19885089  0.21088713  0.36490795
                    0.30154228 -1.46724844 -0.9004966   0.51069123]
                  [ 0.15193619 -0.08050451  0.13325857 -0.22897118  0.22460887  0.25148487
                    0.26430339 -1.32499278 -0.76786339  0.51948214]
                  ................
                  [ 0.21231894 -0.03649403  0.1441728  -0.1944664   0.24102062  0.22770482
                    0.27350223 -1.31370342 -0.75460964  0.52975202]
                  [ 0.02851745  0.44122052  0.14630049 -0.20715928  0.12495413  0.72705191
                    0.38662156 -1.8646065  -1.28368688  0.4700928 ]]
```

#### 上記 `print( "y.data_after : ", y.data )` の表示

```
y.data_after :   [[ 0.11127097  0.10363374  0.10957521  0.07743976  0.11665703  0.1360822
                    0.12772679  0.02178241  0.03839221  0.15743968]
                  [ 0.11328325  0.08978793  0.11118703  0.07739978  0.12182236  0.12514086
                    0.12675531  0.02586685  0.04515458  0.1636021 ]
                  ................
                  [ 0.1182229   0.09218144  0.11043484  0.07871128  0.12166525  0.12005592
                    0.12568201  0.0257015   0.04495416  0.16239065]
                  [ 0.09137783  0.13806245  0.10280006  0.07219178  0.10062892  0.18374288
                    0.13072647  0.01376156  0.02460128  0.14210671]]
```

ただし、試しのため、バッチサイズは２０、エポック数は３回での実行結果なので、
精度は望めませんが、正解ラベルと配列番目とはどうも一致してなさそうです。

### 問題解決のためにしてきたこと

#### 読んだ本

- Chainer による 実践深層学習
- ゼロから作る Deep Learning ( オライリージャパン )

#### ネット検索

かれこれ、２〜３ヶ月前からずっと検索しています。
AutoEncoder で、入力画像を出力に再現させるサンプルプログラムは、沢山ヒットしましたが、
AutoEncoder の学習で特徴を抽出したあとに、テストデータを入力し、
どの分類になるかのサンプルプログラムはなかなかヒットしません。
( 正解率を求めるサンプルプログラムはヒットしますが )

どなたかどうぞ宜しくお願いします。

Comment: **追加**　ひとつ間違いがありました。Softmax関数を使う場合は、非負値でなければならないとのことなので、直前に　F.relu( y )　を挿入しました。

Comment: autoencoderは教師なし学習で出力は正解ラベルの情報なしの状況で学習され出力されるものなので、そのままではラベルの予測値を出力したことにはなっていません。参考にされているホームページの例でも正解ラベルの情報を使わず学習し2次元の出力を可視化してみて、その後プロットの配置とラベルの関係をみてみるとラベルごとに分離しているように見えるということを確認しています。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございました。autoencoderは教師なし学習で出力は正解ラベルの情報なしの状況で学習され出力されるものなので、そのままではラベル‌​の予測値を出力したことにはなっていません‌​。参考にされているホームページの例でも正‌​解ラベルの情報を使わず学習し2次元の出力‌​を可視化してみて、その後プロットの配置と‌​ラベルの関係をみてみるとラベルごとに分離‌​しているように見えるということを確認して‌​います。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございました。"autoencoderは教師なし学習で、出力は正解ラベルの情報なしの状況で入力と同じにして特徴を抽出するもの" であることは理解しておりますが、その後で、この抽出した特徴を使って、テストデータの分類予測を出力させるにはどのようにすればいいのでしょうか？？お手数をお掛け致しておりますが、どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Comment: @takoika様　ご返信ありがとうございました。"autoencoderは教師なし学習で、出力は正解ラベルの情報なしの状況で入力と同じにして特徴を抽出するもの" であることは理解しておりますが、その後で、この抽出した特徴を使って、テストデータの分類予測を出力させるにはどのようにすればいいのでしょうか？？お手数をお掛け致しておりますが、どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 通常の教師あり学習として学習する方法があります。この場合10次元のautoencoderの出力をx、正解ラベルをyとして、xからyを予測する問題として学習します。autoencoderですでにいい感じの特徴量は抽出されているはずなのでxからyの予測手法としてはロジスティック回帰などの簡単な手法が使われます。

Comment: @takoika様　ありがとうございます。まさしく、takoika様のご説明いただきました通りで、特徴抽出は Auto-Encoder を使って、その後、少ない教師ありデータの入力を MLP に掛ければとの思いで始めました。
その場合の Chainer または Keras での実現方法(使い方)に苦慮し続けております。
特徴抽出しましたパラメータ群(ファイル)を MLP専用のプログラム側で読み出して利用するといいのでしょうか？？
どうぞ宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: はいそれでいいと思います。autoencoderの学習と抽出された特徴からラベル予測する学習は別なのでいったんautoencoderの出力を保存して、それを入力ベルトルとして使えばよいです。

Comment: @takoika様　何度もありがとうございました。
アドバイス頂きました切り込み方で、早速もう一度チャレンジしてみます。ご親切、感謝申し上げます。どうもお世話になりました。御免ください。